# Como convertir cada renglón de archivo en un elemento de una lista?

Tags: python

Necesito que el programa al leer un documento de texto cada vez que encuentre un salto e linea (\n), convierta el texto leido anterior al salto de linea en un elemento de una lista.

Con la función "split" no sirve por que convierte cada palabra en un elemento de lista y eso no es lo que necesito, necesito que cada renglon sea un elemento de lista.

¿Alguien conoce algún método o expresión regular para hacerlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar el método [splitlines](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines)

```
texto = """Una linea
Segunda linea
Tercera linea"""

lista = texto.splitlines()
print(lista)
```

> ['Una linea', 'Segunda linea', 'Tercera linea']